# viewDidLoad not called for UIView Inside UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, viewdidload

I have got a `UITabBarController` in nib file. Usually 2 tabbar items are pre-added. I added third tabBar item to it by dragging a `UIViewController` and changing class name in identity inspector to the controller I want to load - lets say `abc`. When I run my program, both viewController load fine except that of abc. The contents are displayed as it is set in IB, the code I wrote in viewDidLoad is not executing. I confirmed it by using breakpoints and NSLog statements.

But the weird thing is that when I tried to load this nib separately by pushing it into `UINavigationController`, it is doing fine.

So my Question here is What is going wrong when I try to load it in `UITabBarController`? Why `viewDidLoad` is not executing?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you linked this view controller to a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared whole product and then built again after restarting mac. Now everything is working fine. My guess is may be new changes were not made in cache on built, which was the source of problem. Any person can comment to tell the reason he can think of in his mind. I will love to know that ;)